# Merge two lists with common key in Java

Tags: java, json

I am getting one list from an AS400 query and another from a SQL Server query. I need to merge these two lists into a single list.  The first list is every asset in our inventory and looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "assetId": 0,
        "type": "OV",
        "truckNumber": "L122",
        "longitude": 0,
        "latitude": 0,
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "assetId": 0,
        "type": "PO",
        "truckNumber": "SQ46",
        "longitude": 0,
        "latitude": 0,
        "id": 0
    }
]
```

The second list has more detail and looks like this, with both lists having one field in common, truckNumber:

```
[
   {
        "trailerGroup": "C",
        "assetId": 308,
        "loaded": false,
        "dedicated": false,
        "intermodal": false,
        "sealed": false,
        "truckNumber": "L122",
        "companyOwned": true,
        "onSite": false,
        "customerId": "KTPH",
        "id": 308,
        "modified": {
            "when": 1546498401156
        },
        "created": {
            "when": 1546498401156
        }
    },
    {
        "trailerGroup": "C",
        "assetId": 309,
        "loaded": false,
        "dedicated": false,
        "intermodal": false,
        "sealed": false,
        "truckNumber": "SQ46",
        "companyOwned": true,
        "onSite": true,
        "customerId": "KTPH",
        "id": 309,
        "modified": {
            "when": 1546498401156
        },
        "created": {
            "when": 1546498401156
        }
    }
]
```

I need to update any existing values like longitude while adding any that are not in the first query.

I tried some of the merge examples but none work at all or others just append the first list to the second list.

---

**Possible Solution:**

Anyone see an issue with this?

```
List<Trailer> trailers = null;
List<Trailer> trailersAS400 = null;
List<Trailer> trailersSQLServer = null;

try {
    trailersAS400 = getTrailerAS400Proxy().getTrailers();
    trailersSQLServer = getTrailerSQLServerProxy().getTrailers();           

    Map<String, Trailer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Trailer t : trailersAS400) {
        map.put(t.getNumber(), t);
    }
    for (Trailer t : trailersSQLServer) {
        String key = t.getNumber();
        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.get(key).setNumber(t.getNumber());
        } else {
            map.put(key, t);
        }
    }
    trailers = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

}
```

Comment: A simple way to do this would be to first map both lists to maps using the `truckNumber` as the key and the item itself as the value. Then you can iterate over the keyset and get the same item from both maps, joining them together into whatever fashion you would like.

Comment: What about creating a merged list of Java objects and then converting back to JSON (assuming you need the merged list in JSON)?

Comment: Map looks promising but this has to be compatible with JRE 1.7 so no lamda expressions.

Comment: Change if condition to         if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
            map.put(key, t);
        }          Anyway TruckNumber is same in both the objects. Why you are setting it Again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Jackson` (one of the most popular JSON libraries), you can simply achieve this as follows:

**Code Snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mepper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Object>> listAs400 = mepper.readValue(jsonStrAs400, List.class);
List<Map<String, Object>> listSqlServer = mepper.readValue(jsonStrSqlServer, List.class);
listAs400.forEach(e1 -> {
    listSqlServer.forEach(e2 -> {
        if (e1.get("truckNumber").toString().equals(e2.get("truckNumber").toString())) {
            e2.forEach((k, v) -> {
                e1.put(k, v);
            });
        }
    });
});
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(listAs400));
```

**Console Output**

```
[ 
  { 
    "assetId":308,
    "type":"OV",
    "truckNumber":"L122",
    "longitude":0,
    "latitude":0,
    "id":308,
    "trailerGroup":"C",
    "loaded":false,
    "dedicated":false,
    "intermodal":false,
    "sealed":false,
    "companyOwned":true,
    "onSite":false,
    "customerId":"KTPH",
    "modified":{ 
      "when":1546498401156
    },
    "created":{ 
      "when":1546498401156
    }
  },
  { 
    "assetId":309,
    "type":"PO",
    "truckNumber":"SQ46",
    "longitude":0,
    "latitude":0,
    "id":309,
    "trailerGroup":"C",
    "loaded":false,
    "dedicated":false,
    "intermodal":false,
    "sealed":false,
    "companyOwned":true,
    "onSite":true,
    "customerId":"KTPH",
    "modified":{ 
      "when":1546498401156
    },
    "created":{ 
      "when":1546498401156
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the example below. I believe this fulfills your requirements of merging your two lists, updating any existing values and finally adding any that are not in the first query.

In addition, I took into consideration that you are using Java Runtime Environment 7(JRE 1.7).

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class App {

    private static String path1 = "C:\\path\\to\\AS400.json";
    private static String path2 = "C:\\path\\to\\SQL_Server_query.json";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JSONArray trailersAS400 = null;
        JSONArray trailersSQLServer = null;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(path1);
            FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(path2);
            // utilize simple json parser to parse json objects
            trailersAS400 = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(fr);
            trailersSQLServer = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(fr2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); // store parsed JSON's data in a list
        for (Object trSQL : trailersAS400) {
            list.add(trSQL);
        }
        for (Object tr400 : trailersSQLServer) {
            list.add(tr400);
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // maps truck L122 key value pairs
        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // maps truck SQ46 key value pairs
        for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) { // iterate through list and update map1 with key value pair.
            HashMap<String, Object> truck = (HashMap<String, Object>) iter.next();
            if (truck.containsValue("L122")) {
                Set<Entry<String, Object>> s = truck.entrySet();
                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : s) {
                    map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            } else if (truck.containsValue("SQ46")) { // iterate through list and update map2 with key value pair.
                Set<Entry<String, Object>> s = truck.entrySet();
                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : s) {
                    map2.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        // Update map with map1 & map2. Note the key is represented as the truck number.
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("L122", map1);
        map.put("SQ46", map2);
        Gson pp = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String p = pp.toJson(map);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

output:

```
{
  "L122": {
    "truckNumber": "L122",
    "dedicated": false,
    "sealed": false,
    "created": {
      "when": 1546498401156
    },
    "latitude": 0,
    "type": "OV",
    "loaded": false,
    "intermodal": false,
    "companyOwned": true,
    "assetId": 308,
    "customerId": "KTPH",
    "onSite": false,
    "modified": {
      "when": 1546498401156
    },
    "trailerGroup": "C",
    "id": 308,
    "longitude": 0
  },
  "SQ46": {
    "truckNumber": "SQ46",
    "dedicated": false,
    "sealed": false,
    "created": {
      "when": 1546498401156
    },
    "latitude": 0,
    "type": "PO",
    "loaded": false,
    "intermodal": false,
    "companyOwned": true,
    "assetId": 309,
    "customerId": "KTPH",
    "onSite": true,
    "modified": {
      "when": 1546498401156
    },
    "trailerGroup": "C",
    "id": 309,
    "longitude": 0
  }
}
```

For the purpose of performance. You may consider using a LinkedHashMap versus a HashMap as is done in the example above. Iterating is more efficient when using a LinkedHashMap. The below example uses this approach.

```
public class App {

private static String path1 = "C:\\path\\to\\AS400.json";
private static String path2 = "C:\\path\\to\\SQL_Server_query.json";


    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JSONArray trailersAS400 = null;
        JSONArray trailersSQLServer = null;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(path1);
            FileReader fr2 = new FileReader(path2);
            // utilize simple json parser to parse json objects
            trailersAS400 = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(fr);
            trailersSQLServer = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(fr2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); // store parsed JSON's data in a list
        for (Object trSQL : trailersAS400) {
            list.add(trSQL);
        }
        for (Object tr400 : trailersSQLServer) {
            list.add(tr400);
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // maps truck L122 key value pairs
        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>(); // maps truck SQ46 key value pairs
        Iterator<Object> iter = list.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) { // iterate through list and update map1 with key value pair.
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> truck = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(); 
            truck.putAll((Map<? extends String, ? extends Object>) iter.next());
            if (truck.containsValue("L122")) {
                Set<Entry<String, Object>> s = truck.entrySet();
                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : s) {
                    map1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            } else if (truck.containsValue("SQ46")) { // iterate through list and update map2 with key value pair.
                Set<Entry<String, Object>> s = truck.entrySet();
                for (Entry<String, Object> entry : s) {
                    map2.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        // Update map with map1 & map2. Note the key is represented as the truck number.
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("L122", map1);
        map.put("SQ46", map2);
        Gson pp = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String p = pp.toJson(map);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

Both example code will produce your desired results as indicted in the above output.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko - Did my implementation above fulfill your requirement?

Comment: It feels like you made the solution more complicated than it needs to be.  It may work but the first solution does as well.  I'm not seeing the benefits.

Comment: I was trying to provide you an answer based on your comments; however, if the first solution your referring to is the one in your original post merges the two lists then I would go with that. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you.  Just trying to learn why one solution is better than another.  Wasn't aware of LinkedHashMap until now.